# Can an app initiate other app without permission?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions

For example a user "force stop" an app X, and when user opens my app, and can my app initiate an app X ?. Is it legal? There wont be any security flaw? If I can initiate an app X, I can also access the initiate methods of, many apps right? Does Android allows it? is it legal to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "initiate an app"? What do you mean by "access the initiate methods"?

Comment: You should read Intents guide. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters